# Exception Handler not working on a spring boot app

Tags: spring

I have created a spring boot application defined like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

I have also created a RestController for this application with a request mapping

I have then created a specific exception :

```
public class MyOwnException extends Exception {

    public MyOwnException (String message) {
        super(message);

    }

}
```

And then defined a class for globalling handling all of my exception

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class MyOwnExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MyOwnException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "File or folder is unwrittable")
    public @ResponseBody
    ExceptionJSONInfo handleMyOwnException(
            HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
        ExceptionJSONInfo response = new ExceptionJSONInfo();
        response.setUrl(request.getRequestURL().toString());
        response.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return response;
    }
```

Here is my controller code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/you/should")
public class MyOwnController {
        @RequestMapping(value="/try/this", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
        public FileSystemResource processSomething(HttpServletResponse response) throws MyOwnException {
        FileSystemResource afileRessource = new FileSystemResource();
        if (true)
throw new MyOwnException("File not readable: " + finalFileWithEncryptedName);           
                return afileRessource
        }
}
```

Unfortunately the handler is never been called instead I get following stacktrace :

```
2015-02-26 17:37:34.914 ERROR 6512 --- [nio-9050-exec-5] .a.c.c.C.[.[.[.p.k.p.[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/myOwnContext] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is MyOwnException: My onw exception message] with root cause MyOwnException: MyOwnExceptionMessage
at MyOwnController.myOwnCOntrollerMethod(MyOwnController.java:164)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:280)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Can anybody please help me find why my `ControllerAdvise` is never being called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding @EnableWebMvc annotation to your configuration class and make sure your controller advice is being scanned.

Comment: So I added the @EnableWebMvc and nothing changed unfortunately

Comment: Regarding your comment on the controller advice here is what I see in the log : `015-02-26 22:46:15.877  INFO 458 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1b5eb475: startup date [Thu Feb 26 22:46:12 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2`

Comment: Can u show me package structure of your configuration and controlleradvice

Comment: All the file are in a single hello package Also I've changed class Application annotation in order to use the @SpringBootApplication annotation

Comment: I tried a simple boot with the same thing and it works for me. i had a simple exception handler like the one below, since i don't have ExceptionJSONInfo. Try a simple exception handler and see if it is working.    @ExceptionHandler({ MyOwnException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "File or folder is unwrittable")
    public @ResponseBody
    String handleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception exception) {
        return exception.getMessage();
    }

Comment: Hi minion, it works when I do it from the command line :      `MacBook-Pro-de-Serge:JavaVirtualMachines sergekouthon$ curl http://localhost:8080/
{"timestamp":1425018965667,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","exception":"hello.MyOwnException","message":"File or folder is unwrittable","path":"/"}`    But when doing it from a safari browser I still get the standard White Label Page configured in spring boot instead of the json message

Comment: Well. if you want data to be returned from exceptionhandler, then don't have the @ResponseStatus annotation. Take a look at the below article which helps in how to handle different exception scenarios. Hope this helps. http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc. Also accept/upvote hoping my answer helped.

Comment: Yes Indeed, but I am having trouble finding a way to accept/upvote your answer. Let me Check. And BTW thanks a lot !

Comment: Thank you ! And sorry for the delay !

Comment: Omg, saved me so much pain, by "make sure your controller advice is being scanned" my package with exception handler was wrongly named and it was never scanned!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has the same problem and "adding @EnableWebMvc annotation to your configuration class" didn't solve the problem, the solution can be in correctly naming your package. If your package is wrongly named it won't be scanned and therefore exception handler will never be triggered.

More about packages here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-packages

Basically your package and directory structure should be the same...

Answer (score 0):

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
```

works for me,

`@EnableWebMvc` does not.

Spring boot 2.0